# Want to extract the first letter of each word

Tags: perl, sas

I basically have a variable `COUNTRY` along with variables `SUBJID` and `TREAT` and I want to concatenate it like this *ABC002-123 /NZ/ABC*.

Suppose if the COUNTRY variable had the value 'New Zealand'. I want to extract the first letter of each word, But I want extract only the first two letters of the value when there is only one word in the COUNTRY variable. I wanted a to know how to simply the below code. If possible in **perl programming**.

```
If COUNTW(COUNTRY) GT 1 THEN 
  CAT_VAR=
   UPCASE(SUBJID||"/"||CAT(SUBSTR(SCAN(COUNTRY,1,'     '),1,1),
                 SUBSTR(SCAN(COUNTRY,2,' '),1,1))||"/"||TREAT);
```

Comment: What this has to do with Perl? This code does not look like Perl at all

Comment: This has got nothing to do with Perl. But I'm learning how to incorporate Perl in SAS, so wanted a solution in Perl.

Comment: I assume that with perl programming you mean using a Perl Regular Expression. What should happen if the country name consists of more than 2 words?

Comment: So far I haven't encountered a string value with more than two words in the COUNTRY variable.

Comment: If you're going to put a bounty on a question with several seemingly valid answers, please explain why each of those does not meet your needs, and what further information you need.

Comment: I wanted a little more attention to the question. I recently started to incorporate Perl regular expression in my SAS codes and wanted a another input from people to help me get to know more about the Perl regular expression usage.

Comment: Understood.  You might want to make it clear what areas you're curious about and/or not sure about - you would likely get better assistance that way.  If you need me to explain more about parts of my answer (if some of it is unclear or inspecific) let me know in the answer comments specifically which areas you're not sure about.

Comment: The coding is interesting but you're doing it weird. You should do a one-time calculation to make the abbreviations of countries then look them up rather than calculating it each time. And there is already a nice, standard 2-letter abbreviation for countries called "ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 code" you should look into. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I'm learning SAS and i had to do it with Functions only. But at the same time I want to learn how to incorporate Perl regular expressions in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize the OP might not be interested in another answer, but for other users browsing this thread and not wanting to use Perl expressions I suggest the following simple solution (for the original `COUNTRY` variable):

```
FIRST_LETTERS = compress(propcase(COUNTRY),'','l');
```

The propcase functions capitalizes the first letters of each word and puts the other ones in lower case. The compress function with `'l'` modifier deletes all lower case letters.
`COUNTRY` may have any number of words.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @COUNTRY = ("New Zealand", "Germany");

# 'NZ', 'GE'
my @two_letters = map {
  my @r = /\s/ ? /\b(\w)/g : /(..)/;
  uc(join "", @r);
} @COUNTRY;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still learning Perl regular expressions and I'm trying to incorporate Perl regular expressions in SAS.

Answer (score 4):

The SAS Perl Regular Expression solution is to use `CALL PRXNEXT` along with `PRXPOXN` or `CALL PRXPOSN` (or a similar function, if you prefer):

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 country $20.;
datalines;
New Zealand
Australia
Papua New Guinea
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
length country_letter $5.;
prx_1 = prxparse('~(?:\b([a-z])[a-z]*\b)+~io');
length=0;
start=1;
stop = length(country);
position=0;
call prxnext(prx_1,start,stop,country,position,length);
do while (position gt 0);
    matchletter = prxposn(prx_1,1,country);
    country_letter = cats(country_letter,matchletter);
    call prxnext(prx_1,start,stop,country,position,length);
    put i= position= start= stop=;  
end;
run;
```

Comment: @Nimit_ZZ If this answer does not meet your needs, please explain how it may be improved to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @country = ('New Zealand', 'Germany', 'Tanzania', 'Mozambique', 'Irish Repuublic');

my ($one_word_letters, $two_word_letters, @initials);
foreach (@country){
        if ($_ =~ /\s+/){ # Captures CAPs if 'country' contains a space
            my ($first_letter, $second_letter) = ($_ =~ /([A-Z])/g); 
            my ($two_word_letters) = ($first_letter.$second_letter);
            push @initials, $two_word_letters; # Add to array for later
        }
        else {  ($one_word_letters) = ($_ =~ /([A-Z][a-z])/); # If 'country' is only one word long, then capture first two letters (CAP+noncap)
        push @initials, $one_word_letters; # Add this to the same array
    }   
}       

foreach (@initials){ # Print contents of the capture array:
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
NZ
Ge
Ta
Mo
IR
```

This should do the job provided there really are no 3 word countries. Easily fixed if there are though...

Answer (score 2):

This should do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$init = &getInitials($ARGV[0]);

if($init)
{
    print $init . "\n";
    exit 0;
}
else
{
    print "invalid name\n";
    exit 1;
}


1;

sub getInitials {
    $name = shift;
    $name =~ m/(^(\S)\S*?\s+(\S)\S*?$)|(^(\S\S)\S*?$)/ig;
    if( defined($1) and $1 ne '' ) {
        return uc($2.$3);
    } elsif( defined($4) and $4 ne '' ) {
        return uc($5);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```